# Как сделать дерево файлов в ткинтер?

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. Мне нужно сделать дерево файлов вот такого типа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при этом при нажатии на файл выводилось его название.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def function_for_tree():
   print() #название файла

#дерево файлов 

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте tkinter.ttk
там есть элемент treeview который позволяент создавать списки предложенного вами примера

```
t=tkinter.ttk.Treeview(height=40,column=3)
t.pack()
t.insert('что-то',куда)
t.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>',pr)
t.place(x=0,y=20)
```